# Performance of dynamically loading elements using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, dynamic, lazy-loading, loading

I was looking at dynamically loading css stylesheets, javascript scripts, html elements with javascript.  It all seemed fine, but I was wondering what was the drawback of loading this way?  What are the advantages and the disadvantages of doing something like this? What if I loaded a whole page this way?

Does the page load slower?

Does this make the page loading more synchronous/asynchronous?

Does this flood the server with requests? (e.g. lazy loader)

Does this hog the server's or client's resources?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does the page load slower?
>
> Does this flood the server with requests? (e.g. lazy loader)

Yes and No to both.

The page is loaded very fast if it has little content in them. Typically you will only want to load *what is neccessary*, hence *"lazy load"*. For the first page load, you might want to load your CSS that is necessary. As for JS, you might want to load them last (just before `</body>`) since loading scripts is inconsistent in browsers (some load parallel, some load in series. but they execute in the order defined). it's just to be safe also, that the elements you need to manipulate in these scripts exist when you execute them (but we are saved by jQuery's `.ready()` these days)

as for flooding the server.. err.. more like hogging "pipes". browsers have around 2-8 "pipes" to download files. for example, IE6 has 2 pipes. if you have one video streaming already, it's taking a pipe which means the rest of the stuff has to load using the other pipe, and now they load in series - making it slow. one way to mitigate this is to minify (shrink) and merge (put into one) your files. personally, i merge libraries (jQuery and others) since they never get changed at all. CSS that don't get changed often, i compress and merge. not only that they are smaller, they are less files - no hogging the pipes

> Does this make the page loading more synchronous/asynchronous?

webpages always parsed top-to-bottom, but their download depends on how they are handled in the browser. some browsers load files in parallel, some in series (like scripts in IE) but they get executed top-to-bottom. that's why scripts should be loaded last since parsing hampers the execution thread. an unresponsive script in the middle of the page will halt processing halfway into the page.

> Does this hog the server's or client's resources?

server resources, yes. if you have too many files to request, it does put stress to your server. that's why you need to have a cache system, both script and browser cache. by browser cache, i mean the natural cache which stores CSS, JS, images and so on. however, AJAX is NOT cached (as far as i know) and that's why you need to implement your own cache in JS.

Let's take for example Twitter. you view a person's tweets. the flow is that you click, AJAX request for the posts, load to view and done. now, you want to view another guy. same procedure. *now you want to go back* to the other person. would you as a programmer/server maintainer want to load that content again? would you want to request again? NO, instead, programmers use an object/local storage to store the data. that way, there is no unnecessary requests. as for expiry.. you'll have to figure that out.

overall, it's both advantageous and disadvantageous. it's not like introducing a cure for all problems. it's like having a gun, you can protect yourself but harm others, or the other way around. it's just finding that balance that makes it all work out.

Comment: Thanks for the browsers pipes info, did not know that.  But for flooding the server for requests, I was wondering if for each new element added to the DOM that required a resource like an image, stylesheet, script would require a separate http request.  Is this the case? If it is, how do you optimize this?

Comment: the browser only loads an image once, no matter how many times that image is used in the page (notice how multiple instances of one animated GIF move at the same time). and yet, getting a resource from the server requires a request. however, you have the browser cache to help you. getting stuff that are cached are retrieved from the cache instead of being requested from the server.. until they expire.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on your specific needs. It's not really recommended when you don't have lots of css, etc. The HTML is better if you **don't** load it dynamically since, if you want a SEO friendly site, that's the most important content, and loading it with javascript won't get anything to a search engine.

Here you have a simple snippet to pre-load images. Sometimes it's useful if, for example, you have buttons or elements with hover images and you don't want them to show how they load when you put the mouse over them.

```
var preloadcache = [];
var preloadImages = function(arr){
    for(var i in arr){
        preloadcache.push(function(){
            var img = document.createElement("img");
            img.setAttribute("src",arr[i]);
            return img;
        }());
    }
}
```

Just put all the resources in an array and call the function with it:

```
var myimages = ['path/to/image.png','another/path/example.jpg','ohyes.gif'];
preloadImages(myimages);
```

However, if you want to load elements to the body or head of the DOM, just create them and append them like this:

```
var body = documents.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
var head = documents.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];

// then prepare your elements

var p = document.createElement("p");
p.setAttribute("class","myclass");
p.innerHTML = 'some text with <span> html </span>';

// the append them

body.appendChild(p);
```

Do that with scripts, but try to NOT include code inside the innerHTML, but put them on separate files and just set their src attributes. Be careful since they'll run once you append them. Try to use `document.onload = function(){ ... }` for that.